# FTP link opens to blank page

Tags: ftp

I completely new to using FTP and attempted to open an FTP of one my colleagues.

ftp://ftp.iucaa.in/in.coming/blah/blah

(I can post the actual FTP link if you would like.)

When I click on this though, the link appears in the address bar, but the webpage is blank. I tried this already with two different OS (Linux, Chrome OS) and browsers (firefox, chrome). Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What FTP server does your colleague run?

Comment: ftp://ftp.iucaa.in/in.coming/susmitadas/Shashi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried this already with two different OS (Linux, Chrome OS) and browsers (firefox, chrome).

Firefox have removed FTP support since [Firefox 88 -- April 19, 2021](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/88.0/releasenotes/).

Google Chrome also have already removed FTP support since [Chrome 88 -- December 3, 2020](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/12/chrome-88-deps-rems).

> attempted to open an FTP of one my colleagues.

Use a good FTP client, or use a better file transfer protocol.